# Noise texture on top of a toon shader

Tags: materials, shaders, toon-shading

I am trying to add a noise texture on top of a toon shaded object which also has a wave texture effect. The object is slightly darker than it should be (for example the light grey should be pure white as it's set to #ffffff.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the nodes.

[image: Blender nodes]

I uploaded the file [here](https://www.file.io/EE91/download/GpwVrEyFpsXK) if it helps

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a Mix Shader node to mix with nothing before mixing with the second (bottom) colorramp?

Comment: No reason, I'm just quite new to Blender :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for your particular setup, this should suffice (through its hard to tell without knowing your desired final result) Since the toon group node comes with a color input, it makes sense that you might as well use it:

[image: ToonLight]

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!